# Android ClickableSpan DialogFragment IllegalStateException on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to display a dialog when a certain word in the TextView is clicked. It works fine until I rotate the screen. The log shows a new span is created but `onClick` of the old cancelled one is called. I use DialogFragment and when touch outside the dialog will be cancelled.

```
MainActivity: in onCreate(): MainActivity@c1ad544
MyClickableSpan: in MyClickableSpan(): MainActivity@c1ad544 | MyClickableSpan@ac63b59

/* clicked the text */
MyClickableSpan: in onClick(): MainActivity@c1ad544 |  MyClickableSpan@ac63b59

/* dismissed the dialog and rotated the screen */
MainActivity: in onCreate(): MainActivity@7eb1060
MyClickableSpan: in MyClickableSpan(): MainActivity@7eb1060 | MyClickableSpan@7490811
InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to root view being removed

/* clicked the text again */
MyClickableSpan: in onClick(): MainActivity@c1ad544 | MyClickableSpan@ac63b59
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1411)
```

I create a MyClickableSpan in the MainActivity's `onCreate` and pass `this` as a context to MyClickableSpan's constructor to obtain a FragmentManager later. Code that displays the dialog is:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View widget) {
    MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
    fragment.show(fm, "MyDialogFragment");
}
```

Comment: I cleaned the project and rebuilded and it works now. Don't know if it's a bug of Android Studio or gradle.